# Levinson-Durbin recursion in Julia DSP package

Tags: time-series, julia, signal-processing

I want use to use Levinson-Durbin recursion in Julia, it was suggested that I should use DSP package, but I couldn't find the usage of "LPCLevinson"

```
Pkg.add("DSP")
using DSP
using Distributions
ab=[1:5]
LPCLevinson(ab,4)
```

Comment: have you tried `lpc(ab,4,LPCLevinson())`?

Comment: error"MethodError: no method matching lpc(::Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}, ::Int64, ::DSP.LPC.LPCLevinson)
REPLW"

Comment: I change the command as follow,it seems work                              
 ab=[0.2,0.3,0.4]
aa=lpc(ab,2,LPCLevinson())
aa[1] 
It cause the other problem, since the result is different from R and Matlab's levinsion function, I wonder the reason.

Comment: See also https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/blob/master/src/toeplitzsolvers.jl

Comment: Note that, as a general point, something like [1:5] is not what a Matlab user might assume it to be - it's not an array made of values in that range, rather it's an array containing a single value which itself is a `UnitRange` type. `ab=collect(1:5)` will give you the array of values that you can pass on to other functions.